# How to check condition, stop ticker and exit application if condition is true and if not and timeout occurs exit application

Tags: go

On my following code **k==3** and I send true to channel but it does not check **case x,ok** to print "**test passed**" and **os.Exit (20)** (I want the application exit on first true condition and ignore **time.Sleep(timeout)**)

and on the other hand when I change **k:=4** I want the application exit after **10sec** and print "**Timeout occurred**" with **os.Exit(10)**

```
func main() {
    timeout := time.Second * 10
    sleepTime := 5 * time.Second
    done := make(chan bool)
    ticker := time.NewTicker(sleepTime)

    go func() {
        for {
            select {
            case x,ok := <-done:
                if ok {
                    if x {
                        //Test passed
                        log.Println("** Test Passed **")
                        os.Exit(20)
                    }else {
                        //Timeout
                        log.Println("Timeout occurred")
                        os.Exit(10)
                    }
                }
                return
            case <-ticker.C:
                // Validate
                log.Println("ticker")
                //Check for condition and if its true send true to channel
                k := 3
                if k == 3 {
                    done <- true
                }

            }
        }
    }()

    time.Sleep(timeout)
    done <- false
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first case with `k==3` will not work, because you write to the `done` channel, but there's nothing listening to it so it hangs there. If you want to exit for the `k==3` case, instead of writing to the channel put the code that exists right there.

The second part, when `k==4` is probably working, because when main times out, it writes to `done` which will be received by the first case in select. But probably the program is ending before that has a chance to execute. You can put a sleep in main after write to `done` channel to verify that.

Comment: what do you mean "there's nothing listening to it so it hangs there"?

Comment: @arlen, a write to an unbuffered channel will wait until some goroutine reads from it. When you write to the channel, there is no other goroutine reading from it so the write will block indefinitely.

Comment: How can i make a buffed channel and still use my approach?

Comment: It looks like a channel with cap 1 should do:`done := make(chan bool,1)`. This is because you have one goroutine that wants to write to and read from the same channel.

Comment: done := make(chan bool,1) and k:=4 makes the program exit without checking the timeout

Comment: Put sleep at the end of main. Your program terminates before the select case has a chance to execute.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210503/discussion-between-arlen-and-burak-serdar).